# Unity LWRP alternatives for camera stacking

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, graphic-effects

I am working on upgrading a project in unity from a 2018 version to the latest 2019. One of the mechanics of the game is an AR (augmented reality) system. Some of the UI elements appear in the 3D world, but clearly as part of the hud. They need to be transformed as the camera moves, but should always be drawn on top of the 3d scene.

The old project achieved this via camera stacking. All the AR elements were drawn on a different camera which rendered on top of the 3D camera. The clear flags were set to "depth only" and it removed all other elements from that camera.

In the 2019 version of Unity with the Lightweight Render Pipeline (LWRP), the clear flags feature on the camera is missing. To the best of my research, camera stacking has been removed from LWRP.

What are my alternatives? How can I now achieve this effect? I would like to stick to LWRP as I am using Shader Graph for many of the effects in the game.

Comment: Could you do this with a shader that skips the depth test? Or do you need these items to depth-test/z-sort against each other, but not against the world geometry?

Comment: @DMGregory In a perfect world having them z order would be good, but this does sound like a solution if nothing better can come up. Not sure how to do this in shader graph. Not really ready to write my own shaders